# Filtrar datos de DropDownList con otro DropDownList

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Al momento de seleccionar un dato en el primer `DropDownList1`, en el segundo `DropDownList2`, hará un filtro con un *query* de SQL y se pondrán los nuevos datos en su lista.

Por el momento solo tengo este método:

```
public void dropdowns() {

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("CadenaDeConexion");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CustomerNumber FROM tbl_Customer where CustomerSitie='"+DropDownList1.Text +"'", cn);
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader leer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (leer.Read() == true)
    {
            DropDownList2.Text = leer["CustomerNumber"].ToString();
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

Pero no fucniona con `TextChanged`, solo con botón:

```
protected void DropDownList2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dropdowns();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dropdowns();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi amigo debes usar el evento, Selected_Changed.

```html
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="myListDropDown" 
                CssClass="text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myListDropDown_Change" />
```

Comment: Se resolvió con el AutoPosBack, Gracias.